# How to remove port number from URL using gulp js

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-browser-sync

I am using gulpfile.js for compiling development. I want to remove the port number from the url, as my url is looking at mywebsite.dev:8080

The gulpfile.js code is below:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src",
        open: 'external',
        host: 'mywebsite.dev',
        port: 8080
    });

    gulp.watch(['src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Just leave off the port property or set it to 80.  It seems you need to serve it on 8080

Comment: Its working now. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @BadarRashdi I would like to know how you manage to solve this.